# Why does the `using` scope work locally with Start-Job, but not Invoke-Command?

Tags: powershell

Why doesn't PowerShell allow the use of the `using` scope when using `Invoke-Command` locally? According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-7#using-local-variables), the `using` modifier can only be used on remote commands. To quote:

> Beginning in PowerShell 3.0, you can use the Using scope modifier to identify a local variable in a remote command.

This behavior can be demonstrated when running `Invoke-Command` locally:

```
$myServerName = 'www.google.com'
Invoke-Command { ping $using:myServerName }
```

Which throws the following error:

> A Using variable cannot be retrieved. A Using variable can be used only with Invoke-Command, Start-Job, or InlineScript in the script workflow. When it is used with Invoke-Command, the
>   Using variable is valid only if the script block is invoked on a remote computer.

The error indicates that the remote use of the `using` modifier is only valid remotely, with `Invoke-Command`. So, if we try running the same thing using `Start-Job`, what happens?

```
$myServerName = 'www.google.com'
$j = Start-Job { ping $using:myServerName }
while( $j.State -eq 'Running' ){ Start-Sleep -s 1 }
Receive-Job $j
```

Which doesn't throw an error, and I get the output I expect:

```
 Pinging www.google.com [172.217.6.132] with 32 bytes of data:
 Reply from 172.217.6.132: bytes=32 time=20ms TTL=56
 Reply from 172.217.6.132: bytes=32 time=19ms TTL=56
 Reply from 172.217.6.132: bytes=32 time=19ms TTL=56
 Reply from 172.217.6.132: bytes=32 time=19ms TTL=56
```

---

Why does the documentation state that the `using` scope modifier only works remotely when it can be clearly used in local contexts as well? And similarly, if it works in the context of a local `Start-Job`, what stops it from working with a local `Invoke-Command`?

Comment: As of this writing, there are several open issues on GitHub to request improvements to the linked help topic, the main one being https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/5068

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Note: This answer doesn't cover PowerShell *workflows*, because they are *obsolescent technology no longer supported in PowerShell [Core] v6+* - see [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2018/01/10/powershell-core-6-0-generally-available-ga-and-supported/).</sup>

- **For anything that executes *out-of-runspace*, i.e. *doesn't execute directly in the caller's runspace* (thread), you need the [`$using:` scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables#using-local-variables)** in order to **embed variable *values*<sup>[1]</sup> from the caller's scope**, so that the out-of-runspace code can access it.
- Conversely, **all *other* contexts *neither require nor support* `$using:`**.

  - This **includes *local* `Invoke-Command` calls**, such as yours, (due to the absence of a `-ComputerName` or a `-Session` argument); however, such calls are **rarely necessary** (see below).

**Overview of out-of-runspace contexts**:

- **Remotely executed commands**, started with [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command)'s `-ComputerName` parameter.

  - *Runspace-local* use of `Invoke-Command` - which is what happens *without* `-ComputerName` or `-Session` - neither requires nor supports `$using:` references (it runs in a *child scope* of the caller's scope, or, with `-NoNewScope`, directly in the caller's scope).

    - Runspace-local use of `Invoke-Command` is rarely necessary, because the `&`, the [call (execute) operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-) (execution in a child scope), and `.`, the [(dot-)source operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-) (execution directly in the caller's scope), are more concise and efficient alternatives.
  - Note that if you use the `-ComputerName` parameter to target the *local* computer, the command is still treated as if it were a remote execution, i.e., it goes through PowerShell's remoting infrastructure, and the same rules as for true remote execution apply.
- **Background jobs**, started with [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job)
- **Thread jobs**, started via [`Start-ThreadJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob).

  - In PowerShell [Core] v7+, this also includes script blocks passed to
    [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7) with the `-Parallel` switch.

---

**Remotely executed commands and background jobs run *out of process***<sup>[2]</sup>, and for values to cross these process boundaries they undergo **XML-based serialization and deserialization**, which typically involves **loss of type fidelity** - both on input and output.

- See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180367/45375) for background information.
- Note that this doesn't just apply to values embedded via `$using:`, but also to values passed as *arguments* via the `-ArgumentList` (`-Args`) parameter to `Invoke-Command [-ComputerName]` and `Start-Job`.

**Thread jobs**, by contrast, because they run in a different runspace (thread) *in the same process*, **receive `$using:` variable values as their original, live objects** and, similarly, return such objects.

- The **caveat** is that **explicit synchronization across runspaces (threads) may be needed**, if they all access a given, mutable reference-type instance - which is most likely to happen with `ForEach-Object -Parallel`.
- Generally, though, **thread jobs are the better alternative to background jobs in most cases**, due to their significantly better performance, lower resource use, and type fidelity.

---

<sup>[1] Note that this means that out-of-runspace code *can never modify variables in the caller's scope*. However, in the case of *thread* jobs (but not during remoting and not in background jobs), if the variable *value* happens to be an instance of a *reference type* (e.g., a collection type), it *is* possible to modify that instance in another thread, which requires synchronizing the modifications across threads, should multiple threads perform modifications.</sup>

<sup>[2] Unlike remote commands, background jobs run on the *same computer*, but in a (hidden) PowerShell *child process*.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

This is true when using "using" because the definition of using states,

> Beginning in PowerShell 3.0, you can use the Using scope modifier to identify a local variable in a remote command

Anytime you use the `$using`, you have to provide `-ComputerName` or `-Session` arguments whether the target server is localhost or remote.

Ex.

```
$myServerName = 'www.google.com'
Invoke-Command { ping $using:myServerName }
### BIG ERROR.

$myServerName = 'www.google.com'
Invoke-Command { ping $using:myServerName } -computername $env:COMPUTERNAME
### Ping response.

$myServerName = 'www.google.com'
Invoke-Command { ping $myServerName }
### Ping Reponse.
```

`$using:` is only supported in a few, specific contexts, which have one thing in common: code that is being run outside the current runspace - all other contexts neither require nor support it. (@mklement0)

[`Invoke-Command`, `Start-Job`, and `InlineScript` are known contexts which support the use of `$using:` to pass variables in current local session.]

[Documentation on where you can use `$using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-7#using-local-variables)

Comment: Okay, so it needs the `-ComputerName` or `-Session` arguments and it will work even locally. That makes sense, but doesn't explain why it works with a local `Start-Job` without specifying the `-ComputerName`.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest Updated the post. Limitation of `$using` exists in `Invoke-Command` only where it requires -ComputerName or -Session arguments. Start-Job or InlineScripts dont have this limitation.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest, if you use `-ComputerName` to target the _local_ computer, the command still goes through PowerShell's remoting infrastructure, which has serious performance and type-fidelity implications. Doing so really only makes sense to simulate true remoting for _testing_.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the using if it's not remote:

```
invoke-command { ping $myservername }
```

Note that you have to be admin to invoke on localhost.

Comment: More importantly, _you don't need `Invoke-Command` at all_ for _local_ invocations.