# Modifying remote variables inside ScriptBlock using Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

Is it possible to modify remote variables?  I am trying to do something like the following:

```
$var1 = ""
$var2 = ""

Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server1 -ScriptBlock{
$using:var1 = "Hello World"
$using:var2 = "Goodbye World"
}
```

When I try this I get the error:

```
The assignment expression is not valid.  The input to an assignment operator must be an object that is able to accept assignments, such as a variable or a property.
```

So obviously, it doesn't work using this method, but are there any other approaches I could take?  I need to use and modify those variables in both a remote and local scope

Comment: You want the "Hello World" value to be written back to the variables in your local/calling session?

Comment: Well looks like he might be running the command on a remote machine and wants the response back into the first machines variables. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, Mathias.  And there is more than one variable being edited, which makes just returning a single value from the command a little more complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So what you are trying to do wont work. But here is a work around.

Place your data you want returned into a hashtable and then capture the results and enumerate over them and place the value into the variables.

```
$var1 = ""
$var2 = ""

$Reponse = Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server1 -ScriptBlock{
    $Stuff1 = "Hey"
    $Stuff2 = "There"
    Return @{
        var1 = $Stuff1
        var2 = $Stuff2
    }
}

$Reponse.GetEnumerator() | %{
    Set-Variable $_.Key -Value $_.Value
}

$var1
$var2
```

This will return

```
Hey
There
```

Answer (score 3):

What you're trying to do fundamentally cannot work:

**A `$using:` reference to a variable in the *caller's* scope** in script blocks executed *in a different runspace* (such as *remotely*, via `Invoke-Command -ComputerName`, as in your case):

- is *not* a reference to the *variable object* (to the variable as a whole),
- but **expands to the variable's *value***, and **you fundamentally cannot assign something to a *value***.

In the case at hand, `$using:var1` effectively becomes `""` in your script block (the *value* of `$var1` when `Invoke-Command` is called), and something like `"" = "Hello world"` cannot work.

The conceptual help topic [`about_Remote_Variables`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Remote_Variables) (now) mentions that (emphasis added):

> A variable reference such as `$using:var` expands to the *value of* variable `$var` from the caller's context. *You do not get access to the caller's variable object*.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60012780/45375) for background information.

---

As for a **potential solution**:

**Make your script block *output* the values** of interest, **then assign to local variables**, as shown in [ArcSet's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60744253/45375).