# Write-Information does not appear to work in powershell foreach-object -parallel

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing, output, powershell-7.0, foreach-object

I am new to powershell and just learning it.  I have some experience in C#.  I am trying to use the foreach-object -Parallel option but cant get all the Write-* functions to work.

```
function writeTest {
        1..1 | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
            Write-Host "host"
            Write-Output "Output"
            Write-Information "information" -InformationAction Continue
            Write-Verbose "verbose"
            Write-Warning "Warning"
            Write-Error "error"       
        }
}
```

Function called like: writeTest -verbose

Outputs:

```
host
Output
WARNING: Warning
Write-Error: error
```

My question is why doesn't write-verbose and write-information display anything?

Please forgive any ignorance.

Comment: both of those streams are NOT displayed by default. take a look at the respective preference $vars with something like `Get-Variable -Name *prefer*` ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**You're seeing a *bug*** in `ForEach-Object -Parallel` / `Start-ThreadJob`, present up to at least PowerShell Core 7.0:

Your `Write-Information` output *should* show, because you've used `-InformationAction Continue` to turn it on; while your `Write-Verbose` output not showing is expected, because you didn't turn it on with `-Verbose`, it also wouldn't show if you did use `-Verbose`, due to the bug.

See [GitHub issue #13816](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13816).

The **workaround** is to *also* set the *preference variable* `$InformationPreference` in order to turn on the information stream, before calling `ForEach-Object -Parallel` (see below).

**Separately, there's a conceptual problem** with your code:

- You're passing the `-Verbose` common parameter to your `write-Test` function, yet this function isn't declared as an *advanced* function (which requires a `[CmdletBinding()]` attribute above a `param(...)` block and/or at least one parameter with an `[Parameter(...)]` attribute - see [about_Functions_Advanced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced)), so the parameter will have no effect.
- Even if it did take effect, which means that PowerShell translates it into a function-local `$VerbosePreference` variable with value `'Continue'`, the `ForEach-Object -Parallel` block would *not* see that variable, because the `$using:` scope is needed to reference variable values from the caller's scope; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60012780/45375).

To put it all together.

```
function Write-Test {

  # Mark the function as an advanced one, so that it accepts 
  # common parameters such as -Verbose
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param()
  
  # WORKAROUND: Turn the information stream on 
  #             via its *preference variable* AS WELL:
  $InformationPreference = 'Continue'
  
  1..1 | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    Write-Host "host"
    Write-Output "Output"
    Write-Information "information" -InformationAction Continue               
    Write-Verbose "verbose" -Verbose:($using:VerbosePreference -eq 'Continue')
    Write-Warning "Warning"
    Write-Error "error"       
  }

}
  
Write-Test -Verbose
```

Note the *expression* passed to the `-Verbose` switch, of necessity separated from the switch name with `:` - `-Verbose:($using:VerbosePreference -eq 'Continue')` - which in effect only turns on verbose output if the `$VerbosePreference` value in the function's main thread (`$using:`) is set to `'Continue'`, which in turn happens when `-Verbose` is passed to the advanced function from the outside (it would also happen if `$VerbosePreference` were set to `'Continue'` in the *caller's* scope, due to PowerShell's dynamic scoping; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36347515/45375)).

---

**General information about PowerShell output streams**:

- Both `Write-Verbose` and `Write-Information` are *silent by default*, as is `Write-Debug`.
- You can make their output show in one of two ways:

  - Per-command, via a *common parameter*: Add `-Verbose` to a `Write-Verbose` call and `InformationAction Continue` to a `Write-Information` call (as you've done).
  - Scope-wide, via *preference variables*: set `$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'` and `$InformationPreference = 'Continue'` - but the **caveat** is that neither functions that live in (other) *modules* nor *code that runs in a different thread or process* sees these variables by default:

    - In the module case, you must either use common parameters explicitly or set the preference variable in the *global* scope, which is not advisable; the problem is discussed in [GitHub issue #4568](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4568).
    - In the other thread/process case, the `$using:` scope is required, as shown above.

See [about_Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection), [about_CommonParameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters),  and [about_Preference_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables)