# Using Invoke-Command with Variables in ScriptBlock

Tags: powershell, variables, parameters, invoke-command, scriptblock

New to PowerShell and learning through writing random scripts using the help info. I've tried the following 3 ways to properly get variables into the ScriptBlock(along with way too many small variations to list) with listed error message wrapped in **:

```
do
{
try {
[ValidateRange(1,7)][int]$days = Read-Host "Let's pull up some Warning event logs. How many days back would you like to go back? (1-7)"
} catch {}
} until ($?)

do
{
try {
[ValidateSet('desktop','documents',IgnoreCase)]$location = Read-Host "Would you like me to save the log on your Desktop or in your Documents?"
} catch {}
} until ($?)
$filename = Read-Host "What would you like to name the file?"
$DaysAgo = [datetime]::Now.AddDays(-$days)
Invoke-Command -AsJob -Jobname JobEventLog -ScriptBlock {Get-EventLog -logname system | Where-Object EntryType -eq Warning | where TimeGenerated -ge $DaysAgo | Out-File $HOME\$location\$filename.txt}
```

**Invoke-Command : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.**

---

```
do
{
try {
[ValidateRange(1,7)][int]$days = Read-Host "Let's pull up some Warning event logs. How many days back would you like to go back? (1-7)"
} catch {}
} until ($?)

do
{
try {
[ValidateSet('desktop','documents',IgnoreCase)]$location = Read-Host "Would you like me to save the log on your Desktop or in your Documents?"
} catch {}
} until ($?)
$filename = Read-Host "What would you like to name the file?"
$DaysAgo = [datetime]::Now.AddDays(-$days)
Invoke-Command -AsJob -Jobname JobEventLog -ScriptBlock {Get-EventLog -logname system | Where-Object EntryType -eq Warning | where TimeGenerated -ge $Using:$DaysAgo | Out-File $Using:HOME\$Using:location\$Using:filename.txt}
```

**Invoke-Command : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.**

---

```
do
{
try {
[ValidateRange(1,7)][int]$days = Read-Host "Let's pull up some Warning event logs. How many days back would you like to go back? (1-7)"
} catch {}
} until ($?)
do
{
try {
[ValidateSet('desktop','documents',IgnoreCase)]$location = Read-Host "Would you like me to save the log on your Desktop or in your Documents?"
} catch {}
} until ($?)
$filename = Read-Host "What would you like to name the file?"
Write-Host "Processing..."
$DaysAgo = [datetime]::Now.AddDays(-$days)
$parameters = @{
    ScriptBlock = { Param ($Arg1,$Arg2,$Arg3) Invoke-Command -AsJob -Jobname JobEventLog -ScriptBlock {Get-EventLog -logname system | Where-Object source -eq DCOM | where TimeGenerated -ge $Arg1 | Out-File "$HOME\$Arg2\$Arg3.txt"}}
    JobName = "DCOM"
    ArgumentList = ($DaysAgo,$location,$filename)
}
Invoke-Command @parameters
```

**Invoke-Command : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ScriptBlock'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the command again.**

I'm just looking to have user input how far back they want to view Event Logs, where to save it, and what to name it. I've been able to work my way through everything so far until I hit the Invoke-Command line and haven't been able to get through it. I prefer the one line style of 1 and 2 over the parameters style, however after spending way too much time using the help_Invoke-Command-full and googling I'm throwing in the towel over what I'm sure is a simple error on my syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In order to use [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command)'s `-AsJob` switch, you must execute code *remotely***, such as by targeting a different computer with the `-ComputerName` or `-Session` arguments.

In the absence of such arguments, your command would run *locally*, but it fails due to the syntactic restriction described above.

**If you want to run a job *locally*, use [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job) directly**:

```
$job = Start-Job -Name JobEventLog -ScriptBlock {
    Get-EventLog -logname system | 
      Where-Object EntryType -eq Warning | 
        Where-Object TimeGenerated -ge $using:DaysAgo | 
          Out-File $HOME\$using:location\$using:filename.txt
  }
```

Note: **Since your background script block references variables from the *caller's* scope, they must be referenced via the `$using:` scope** (as you've also done in your last `Invoke-Command`-based attempt). This requirement also applies to script blocks executed *remotely*, such as via `Invoke-Command -ComputerName` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60012780/45375) for background information. The alternative is to pass *arguments* to the script block, via the `-ArgumentList` (`-Args`) parameter, though the `$using:` approach is usually simpler.

`Start-Job` returns a *job-information object* ([`System.Management.Automation.Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Job)), which you can use to monitor the progress of and obtain output from the background job, using the various `*-Job` cmdlets, notably [`Wait-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/wait-job) and [`Receive-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/receive-job) - see the [about_Jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Jobs) conceptual help topic.

Generally, **using `Invoke-Command` for *local* code execution, while technically supported, is rarely necessary**.
For direct, *synchronous* invocation (not as a job) of a command or script block, use `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-) (not needed for single commands, as long as the command name isn't quoted or specified via a variable), or, for execution directly in the caller's scope, `.`, the [dot-sourcing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-) (`. { ... }`).

Comment: No worries, I feel like I was flirting around with the right answer as I had the right ideas just not putting the pieces together properly such as having the $using: but I didn't discover that until after I stopped trying Start-Job and started trying Invoke-Command. The only reason I had started down the Start-Job/Invoke-Command road was I was thinking of requiring a command output to complete before moving on in the script as I wanted to do a Write-Host after it had completed the output(thinking foward if I needed to use this idea for a long running script). Thanks for the help!

Comment: My pleasure, @tigger. Not sure if that's what you ran into, but note that there's a subtle output-synchronization problem that affects even synchronous commands: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43691123/45375

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$args` inside the scriptblock, see an example:

```
$DaysAgo = [datetime]::Now.AddDays(-$days)
Invoke-Command -AsJob -Jobname JobEventLog -ScriptBlock {
Get-EventLog -logname system | Where-Object EntryType -eq Warning | 
where TimeGenerated -ge $args[0] | 
Out-File $HOME\$location\$filename.txt
} -ArgumentList $DaysAgo
```

Add the arguments at the end of the `Invoke-Command` like in the example and use `$args[0]` for the first argument, $args[1] for the second and so on...

Comment: $DaysAgo = [datetime]::Now.AddDays(-$days)
Invoke-Command -AsJob -Jobname JobEventLog -ScriptBlock {
Get-EventLog -logname system | Where-Object EntryType -eq Warning | 
where TimeGenerated -ge $args[0] | 
Out-File $args[1]\$args[2]\$args[3].txt
} -ArgumentList $DaysAgo,$HOME,$location,$filename

This still gives the same error, am I not listing the separate args/argumentlist correctly?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.  The computer is localhost as a test, at an elevated prompt, which you would need for the system log anyway.  Level 3 is warning.  If it was for the same computer you wouldn't need invoke-command at all.

```
$location = 'foo'
$filename = 'myfile'
$date = get-date
$daysago = $date.adddays(-1) 
invoke-command localhost { param($daysago, $location, $filename)
  get-winevent @{logname = 'system'; level = 3; starttime = $daysago} |
  out-file $home\$location\$filename.txt } -args $daysago,$location,$filename
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options. Since you're only running this on your local machine, you can use `Start-Job` instead of `Invoke-Command`.

That being said, the problem that you're running into is 2-fold. First, if you're running the `Invoke-Command` cmdlet, you'll need to specify the ComputerName parameter. Even though it's an optional parameter, you'll need to use it to tell Powershell which parameter set you're using, otherwise it's going to get confused.

Secondly, you'll need to pass the arguments into the scriptblock. This is because Start-Job and Invoke-Command are part of PSRemoting and will actually look for environment variables on the specified computer instead of variables that you've declared in your script.

Here's what worked for me:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $(hostname) -AsJob -JobName "TestJob" -ScriptBlock { Get-EventLog -logname system | Where-Object EntryType -eq Warning | Where-Object -property TimeGenerated -ge $args[0] | Out-File "$HOME\$($args[1])\$($args[2]).txt" } -ArgumentList $DaysAgo, $location, $filename
```

The `Invoke-Command` option is powerful if you're wanting to get this information from other devices on your network.

And here's the `Start-Job` version:

```
Start-Job -Name "TestJob2" -ScriptBlock { Get-EventLog -logname system | Where-Object EntryType -eq Warning | Where-Object -property TimeGenerated -ge $args[0] | Out-File "$HOME\$($args[1])\$($args[2]).txt" } -ArgumentList $DaysAgo, $location, $filename
```

Comment: I suppose I was on the right track at times but had the right answers at the wrong times such as missing the args when I was trying Start-Job in the beginning and then had the args when incorrectly trying Invoke-Command. Thanks!