# Nested Powershell object dereferencing

Tags: powershell, foreach, parallel-processing

I am currently struggling with a relatively simple task.

Currently I want to replace an iteration via foreach with an ForEach-object, since I want to enable parallelization (since the majority of the function is purely waiting for a connection).

So

```
foreach ($vm in $vms)
{
   $output = Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $vm.resourceGroup -VMName $vm.name -ScriptPath ".\script.sh" -CommandId RunShellScript -Verbose
...
   $result | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty "Joins" -Value "$($vm.name.tolower())$($vm.resourceGroup.tolower())$($sub.Id.tolower())"
}
```

will be turned into this:

```
$vms | ForEach-Object -ThrottleLimit 5 -Parallel {
{
   $vm = $_
   $output = Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $vm.resourceGroup -VMName $vm.name -ScriptPath ".\script.sh" -CommandId RunShellScript -Verbose
...
   $result | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty "Joins" -Value "$($vm.name.tolower())$($vm.resourceGroup.tolower())$($sub.Id.tolower())"
}
```

The problem is inside the final result, since the nested derefencing to this property doesn't get parsed properly. I pressume its dereferencing the ForEach-object instead of the designated super-class. Does anybody have an idea how to correctly link them?

Best regards

€DIT:
So since it was asked where the $sub is comming from, here some more detail:

```
foreach ($sub in $Subscriptions)
{
...
   foreach ($vm in $vms)
   {
      $output = Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $vm.resourceGroup -VMName $vm.name -ScriptPath ".\script.sh" -CommandId RunShellScript -Verbose
   ...
      $result | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty "Joins" -Value "$($vm.name.tolower())$($vm.resourceGroup.tolower())$($sub.Id.tolower())"
   }
}
```

Comment: Where is `$sub` defined?

Comment: Previously in another foreach loop, where this function is nested.

Comment: Change `$($sub.Id.tolower())` to `$(($using:sub).Id.ToLower())`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68162798/nested-powershell-object-dereferencing?noredirect=1#comment120470181_68162798

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) has provided the crucial pointer in a comment:

As in background / thread jobs and remoting calls in PowerShell, **including variable values from the *caller's* scope requires use of the [`$using:` scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables#using-local-variables) in [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) `-Parallel` script blocks**.

Since `$sub` in your code is a variable from the caller's scope (as opposed to the block-local `$vm` variable, which receives its value via the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_) representing the *pipeline input* at hand), you need to refer to its value as `$using:sub`.

Therefore, `$($sub.Id.tolower())` must be `$($using:sub.Id.tolower())`

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60012780/45375) for more information about when `$using:` is needed and what its limitations are.