# can not pass a variable filled in a script block to a function outside of the block in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

trying to pass a date from a remote computer to a function in my PS Script. but just gives me junk. from reading i saw that you can not use variables that were declared and intiated inside of a scriptblock on the outside. not sure how to get the date from these PCs. tried to use "$using" and also "$script" but that does not work. get-date works fine directly called to screen

```
    #Fucntion to manipulate the data
Function writeToServer
{
  param($server,$Time)

  # Data preparation for loading data into SQL table 
  $InsertResults = @"
  INSERT INTO [ServerTimeSync].[dbo].[ServerTimes](SystemName,ShownTimeOnServer)
  VALUES ('$SERVER','$Time')
  "@      
  #call the invoke-sqlcmdlet to execute the query
     Invoke-sqlcmd @params -Query $InsertResults
 }



  foreach ($COMPUTER in $COMPUTERS){ 
  icm $COMPUTER -ScriptBlock {$ENV:COMPUTERNAME

    $computer 
    get-date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"

    $script:sdate = get-date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"                        
    } 
      writeToServer $computer $script:sdate      
}
```

Comment: You do not need a format with get-date unless the date is a string.  Without the format it will return a DateTime object.  Try without Format.

Comment: it didnt return anything just a 1900-01-01 date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You can only pass (the values of) local variables TO a remote command, via the [`$using:` scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables#using-local-variables).

  - `$using:` references are embedded directly in the remote script block and are an alternative to passing values via *arguments* (parameters), using `-ArgumentList` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35492490/45375) for examples. In both cases only the *value* of a local variable is getting passed, not the variable object itself.
- The only way to report values FROM a remote command is to have it produce *output*, which you can capture in a variable on the caller's side (`$output = Invoke-Command ...`) or process in a pipeline, as shown below.

  - That is, you fundamentally cannot set *variables* for the *caller* from a remote script block.

Note that the above applies to all *out-of-runspace* / *cross-process* calls, e.g. also to [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60012780/45375) for details.

You can also streamline your command by using parallel processing:

```bash
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $COMPUTERS -ScriptBlock {
  Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"
} | 
  ForEach-Object {
    writeToServer $_.PSComputerName $_      
  }
```

Note:

- If you pass multiple computer names to [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command)'s `-ComputerName` parameter, processing occurs in parallel, but the ordering of the outputs isn't guaranteed to match the order in which the names were passed.
- A [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) call is used to process each object received from the remote call, which inside the script block you can refer to via the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_).
- PowerShell automatically decorates all output objects from a remote script block with ETS (Extended Type System) properties that reflect the invocation context; notably, `.PSComputerName` contains the name of the remote computer.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you utilize $using: correctly

```
$MyString = 'Test 123'
Invoke-Command . -ScriptBlock {Write-Output $MyString} # produces no output because $MyString is empty
Invoke-Command . -ScriptBlock {Write-Output $using:MyString} # produces correct output because $MyString contains the string
```

Output of the remote session can be captured as follows

```
$MyString = 'Test 123'
$Capture = Invoke-Command . -ScriptBlock {Write-Output $using:MyString}
Write-Host $Capture
```